# How can I access an use the objects in my List<dynamic> when they are each passed into an Action<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, lambda, expandoobject

Apologies if this is a duplicate but I can't find it.

Here is the essence of my problem.  Let's assume I have a `List<T>` containing dynamic objects:

```
var collection = new List<dynamic> 
{
    new { Foo = 1, Bar = "Test Text..."},
    new { Foo = 2, Bar = "Test Text #2..."},
    new { Foo = 3, Bar = "Test Text #3..."},
};
```

Now, imagine we want to iterate over this collection, and pass each `dynamic` to an `Action<T>`.  Specifically in my case, I need to pass my objects into a `Parallel.Foreach` call.  I've been able to construct the following code and the application can properly build.

```
Parallel.ForEach(collection, (s) => 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Success!");
    });
```

Of course, this is essentially useless until we operate on the parameter.  What I need to do is access the `s` parameter within the lambda.

Something like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(collection, (s) => 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Foo = {0}, Bar = {1}", s.Foo, s.Bar);
    });
```

However, when I try to write such code I get a VS error stating:

> One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?

How can I access my dynamic object from within my lambda expression?

Comment: The code you showed compiles and runs just fine.  You'll need to provide an example that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: If that goes across assemblies, it won't work.

Comment: @krillgar, it doesn't.  All within the same method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct syntax.  The project was missing a reference to the Microsoft.CSharp .Net assembly. (Doh!)